# Multiple Clients Broadcasting on Same UDP Socket in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I am implementing some sort of auction. 5 users are connected to the same port using a UDP socket on the same address (`INADDR_BROADCAST`) and same port (`udp_port`) assigned previously by `server.c`. Each of them has 10 seconds to offer a price. If 10s pass, the turn will be passed to the next person. Here is how the socket is initialized:

```
udp_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (udp_sockfd < 0)
    error("ERROR opening socket\n");
    
int broadcast_en = 1, opt_en = 1;
setsockopt(udp_sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast_en, sizeof(broadcast_en)); //set broadcasting
setsockopt(udp_sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &opt_en, sizeof(opt_en));
        
bc_adr.sin_family = AF_INET;
bc_adr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);
bc_adr.sin_port = htons(udp_port);

if (bind(udp_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &bc_adr, sizeof(bc_adr)) < 0) 
    error("ERROR on binding");


printf("I am connected to the UDP Socket now\n\n");
```

How I handle the scenario above is with `fd_set`

```
    signal(SIGALRM, sig_handler); //Register signal handler
    printf("Auction beginning...\n");
    alarm(1);
    int mx = -1, ans;

    while (1)
    {
        
        FD_ZERO(&current_sockets);
        FD_SET(udp_sockfd, &current_sockets);
        FD_SET(STDIN, &current_sockets);  //standard input 

        if ((select(udp_sockfd + 1, &current_sockets, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) && (turn_cnt > 5)) //max_fd is udp_sockfd
            perror("ERROR on select");

        
        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN, &current_sockets)) 
        {
            bzero(buffer, 255);
            fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);

            int price = atoi(buffer);

            if (price > mx)
            {
                mx = price;
                ans = turn_cnt;
            }

            bzero(buffer, 255);
            strcat(buffer, "Person with turn ");
            char c[2] = {turn_cnt + '0', '\0'};
            strcat(buffer, c);
            strcat(buffer, " offered price ");
            
            char d[10]; //digits of price
            int sz = 0;
            while (price)
            {
                d[sz++] = '0' + (price % 10);
                price /= 10; 
            }         
            char rd[10];
            for (int i = sz - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
                rd[sz - 1 - i] = d[i];
            rd[sz] = '\n';
            rd[sz + 1] = '\0';
        
            strcat(buffer, rd);
            
            sendto(udp_sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0,(struct sockaddr *)&bc_adr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

            
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(udp_sockfd, &current_sockets)) //something broadcasted on udp_sockfd
        {
            bzero(buffer, 255);
            socklen_t bc_adr_len = sizeof(bc_adr);
            int n = recvfrom(udp_sockfd, buffer, 255, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&bc_adr, &bc_adr_len);
            if (n < 0)
                error("ERROR on reading broadcasted message\n");
            printf("BROADCASTED MESSAGE: %s\n", buffer);
            fflush(stdout);
        }

        if (turn_cnt == 5)
            break;
    }
    
    printf("The winner is user %d with price offer %d\n", ans, mx);
```

There weird thing happening is that, when some user broadcasts its price with some sort of message like: "Person with turn 1 offered price 11" using the `sendto()` function, this message is not received by the other clients until themselves enter their price. For example here is the terminal output of the 3rd client in the queue when he/she enters his/her price:

```
I am connected to the UDP Socket now

Auction beginning...
Person number 1 in queue has 10 seconds to offer his/her price...
Time is up!
Person number 2 in queue has 10 seconds to offer his/her price...
Time is up!
Person number 3 in queue has 10 seconds to offer his/her price...
22
BROADCASTED MESSAGE: Person with turn 1 offered price 11

BROADCASTED MESSAGE: Person with turn 2 offered price 43

BROADCASTED MESSAGE: Person with turn 3 offered price 22
```

The lines starting with "BROADCASTED MESSAGE" corresponding the first and second client, are not being printed on time. They are being printed only when the third client has entered his/her offer which is 22.

The output terminal for the second client is like this:

```
I am connected to the UDP Socket now

Auction beginning...
Person number 1 in queue has 10 seconds to offer his/her price...
Time is up!
Person number 2 in queue has 10 seconds to offer his/her price...
43
BROADCASTED MESSAGE: Person with turn 1 offered price 11

BROADCASTED MESSAGE: Person with turn 2 offered price 43
```

Again it can be seen that the first BROADCAST MESSAGE is not being printed on time.

I have been working on this for two days now and I seriously have no idea why isn't the `sendto()` method being detected by the other clients on-time. Could someone please help me with this? I would like to have the message (price offer) broadcasted for ALL clients simultaneously so they could see what other prices has been offered before their turn.

**Edit**: I have edited some parts of my code as Remy Lebeau said in the comments:

```
    struct sockaddr_in bc_adr_sendto, bc_adr_recvfrom;

    bc_adr_recvfrom.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bc_adr_recvfrom.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    bc_adr_recvfrom.sin_port = htons(udp_port);

    bc_adr_sendto.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bc_adr_sendto.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST); 
    bc_adr_sendto.sin_port = htons(udp_port);

    
    if (bind(udp_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &bc_adr_recvfrom, sizeof(bc_adr_recvfrom)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR on binding");

...

    sendto(udp_sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0,(struct sockaddr *)&bc_adr_sendto, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); 

...

    socklen_t bc_adr_len = sizeof(bc_adr_recvfrom);
    int n = recvfrom(udp_sockfd, buffer, 255, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&bc_adr_recvfrom, &bc_adr_len);
```

But still there is no difference in the result.

**Edit**: Here is the `sig_handler` used for alarm:

```
void sig_handler(int signum)
{ 
    if (turn_cnt != 0)
        printf("Time is up!\n");
    printf("Person number %d in queue has 10 seconds to offer his/her price...\n", ++turn_cnt);
    alarm(10);
}
```

Comment: Problematic string handling, IMHO.

Comment: shouldnt it be if else if: `if ((select(udp_sockfd + 1, &current_sockets, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) && (turn_cnt > 5)) //max_fd is udp_sockfd
            perror("ERROR on select");

        
        if` ?

Comment: You can't `bind()` a socket to a broadcast IP, only to an actual IP that belongs to the local machine. You can only `send/to()` a broadcast IP. Even then, you really shouldn't be using `INADDR_BROADCAST` (`255.255.255.255`), not all network routers allow that. You should send to a subnet's actual broaadcast IP instead (ie, `192.168.xxx.255`).

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Yes, you're right. I should an exit(1) line inside the if for select. But that's not the problem here because there doesn't seem to be an error on selection.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So you are saying that I should eliminate the ```bind()``` line and use ```send()/recv()``` instead of ```sendto()/recvfrom()```? and also use some fixed IP in the format ```(192.168.xxx.255)``` instead of ```(255.255.255.255)```?

Comment: No, I'm saying you can't `bind()` to `INADDR_BROADCAST` as the IP to listen on. You need to `bind()` to an IP of a specific network interface, or to `INADDR_ANY` for all interfaces. You still need `bind()` in order to receive packets with `recvfrom()`. But one issue I do see is that when you call `recvfrom()`, it overwrites `bc_adr` with that peer's info, which means a subsequent `sendto(bc_adr)` will send only to the last peer that you received from. Is that what you really want? I doubt it. To send to `INADDR_BROADCAST`, you should use separate `sockaddr_in`s for `sendto()` and `recvfrom()`

Comment: try to bind to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL if you bind to 127.0.0.1, the socket won't be able to receive broadcasts from the network, only from the local machine

Comment: @RemyLebeau So I should fix two things: First, add another sockaddr_in to separate the ones used for sendto() and recvfrom(). Second, bind the ```sockaddr_in``` that I am using for ```sendto()``` to ```INADDR_ANY```?

Comment: @DaneshvarAmrollahi you need to `bind()` the UDP socket to `INADDR_ANY` (or to the IP of the network interface that was used to `connect()` to the TCP server), then `recvfrom()` using its own `sockaddr_in` (or, just use `NULL`s instead, if you don't care about the sending IP/Port of each UDP packet your client receives), and `sendto()` to `INADDR_BROADCAST` (or to the actual broadcast IP of the subnet the client connected to the server on) using a different `sockaddr_in`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau sorry I thought he was testing locally

Comment: Your terminology needs work, which may be contributing to the confusion. You don't 'connect to a socket'. You connect to a *port*. But in the case of the server you aren't connecting to anything: you are *binding* to an IP:port, which as @RemyLebeau says should be INADDR_ANY:port. Your UDP clients don't connect to anything either: they send and they receive.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. You can see for yourself that it is totally illegible. Edit it into your question, with code formatting. And don't post links to code. Post the code. Code that forms part of a question must be posted in the question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your answers Remy. I just modified the points you mentioned in the edited version of the question. But the output still isn't as desired. I would be thankful if you could please check it again.

Comment: @DaneshvarAmrollahi Well, one problem I see is that you are `alarm()`'ing after just 1 second, not 10 seconds. And if you do receive a message, you are not canceling the alarm. Is there a reason why you are using `SIGALRM` and not the timeout capability of `select()` instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just added the ```sig_handler()``` in the question. I am just using the ```alarm(10)``` in order to print a message every 10 seconds specifying which user's turn it is. Yes, it would be nicer to cancel the alarm whenever the user entered the price, but this would be fine for me too. ```alarm(1)``` is only used to call the ```sig_handler``` for the first time.

Comment: @DaneshvarAmrollahi Have you tried sniffing the network traffic, such as with Wireshark, to see if the packets are actually being transmitted at the time you are expecting? Is the actual problem due to delays in transmission, or delays in processing received packets? It makes a big difference.

Comment: @DaneshvarAmrollahi Also, think of what happens if multiple clients want to submit a price at the same time. You are not identifying the clients in any way, or passing around any IDs inside the packets, you are making assumptions about IDs based solely on your alarms. I would give each client a unique ID, and put those IDs in the packets, then start a timer and just gather up all packets received until the timer elapses, then display the ID of the highest price.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm running this on a local machine and the packets are small. Right? I guess such a delay would be unexpected but maybe it's worth checking. Isn't there any easier way to check the packets instead of using Wireshark?

The weird thing is that whenever a client offers his/her price, then right after that all the BROADCASTED messages from the past are written on the output (in my terminal) meaning that they have been received but not printed on-time (right after it was ```sendto()```ed) as expected.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right with the ID thing. I am just assuming that each client will submit his/her price in his turn. 

But the thing I want is to let each client see the other prices offered by other clients before him/her. I can't just collect all the packets together and just announce the result in the end. I need this broadcasting system. Elsewhere, I would put this duty on my server to collect the offers and announce the result.

Comment: @DaneshvarAmrollahi if you don't want to use Wireshark to troubleshoot this, then I suggest you put the current timestamp inside of each packet given to `sendto()`, and then display that timestamp along with the current timestamp whenever displaying a received packet. Then you can see if there is a descrepency between send time vs receive time.

Comment: can you provide a github link to clone and try fix the project? I will try to help

Comment: I suggest getting rid of the signal handler, and using the `struct timeval` argument to `select()` to implement your timeout instead.  Life is too short to deal with signal handlers if you can avoid them :/

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL I invited you as a collaborator to the repository. There is README.md file there too. Please let me know if you had any questions. You can find my email at my Github profile.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I commented the alarm() functions. The broadcasting seems to be working as desired without it. This alarm() thing is messing up something which I can't find. I guess I should use something else for the timing.

Comment: @DaneshvarAmrollahi you were already told what to use - the `timeval` parameter of `select()`, or a non-alarm timer.